# EaseUS Partition Master has no "Convert GPT to MBR" option

Tags: windows, mbr, gpt, easeus-partition-manager

I have two Windows 7 installation USB pen drives and another one with a bootable EaseUS Partition Master program. I tried to load one of the Windows USB disks and it doesn't load at all (no errors, no idea) and the other one says I can't install windows because my disk is of GPT partition style.

So I loaded EaseUS Partition Master as I don't want to lose my data (hence I don't want to use diskpart) but there's no option to convert from GPT to MBR at all. There's no windows installed on my disk whatsoever so I'm kinda stuck now.

I also tried to read articles and boot the USB using UEFI but I didn't find any relevant option on my BIOS menu, my laptop might be too old (2012).

I think this question has been posted somewhere here but there's no real solution for the not so advanced used, which made me to bring the question again. Also, I still can't comment, just ask :)

Comment: Any laptop from 2012 is very likely UEFI, not BIOS. And the relevant options can be anywhere but usually is in the boot menu.

Comment: I tried to explore all the options available but none related to this problem. There's only a Launch EFI file from a file system or something like that which doesn't help. I tried loading the EFI file from my Windows 7 USB disk but it didn't work.